# Press on textinput hides modal react-native-modal

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-textinput, react-native-modal

I am rendering Flatlist which render list of items each item have button and modal inside it when the button pressed the modal shall open, each modal have some text inputs inside it
so the hierarchy is as the following :

Screen

-FlatList

--Item

---Button

---Modal

----TextInput

When I open press on the first item's button the modal opens and everything works great, but when I scroll down in the Flatlist and press on the last item and open the modal open then I try to write on the modal's textinput the modal disappears.

I am sure that the modal exists but I cannot see it, Any help?

[GIF explaining what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKeBr.gif)

Comment: could you show some code when you click button how modal is showing and when its hiding?

Comment: Have you fixed it ?

Comment: @MauricioJavierBiott Yes, I changed the hierarchy. 
I extracted The Modal from the item and inserted it beside the flat list, and I created a function to open/close the modal and passed it to the items.
I am not sure what the problem was but changing the hierarchy of the components solved it.

Comment: @HazemKhairyMohamed Could you please elaborate on your solution? I'm struggling to solve this, I'll really appreciate this.

Comment: FlatList prop: `removeClippedSubviews = true` is causing the issue because it is the default for Android.
Check the prop and warning, here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#removeclippedsubviews

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a modal inside of a component which is contained in a FlatList (such as in your example) and that component goes out of the viewport, the component will get culled and removed from the hierarchy. That means that the component and its children (including the modal) will stop from rendering.

When you open the text input, the keyboard covers the --Item component, the component gets culled and stops rendering and that means that the modal stops rendering as well.

You can stop this behaviour by setting removeClippedSubviews to **false** (not true). The docs state that the default value is false, but it's actually **true** on Android and **false** on iOS by default. That also means that this problem occurs only on android.

Comment: please note that setting this option to `false` might have a noticeable negative performance impact on android. in those cases, it would be better to pull the modal(s) out of the items. a decent way to do that if the modals need to wary between items is using a navigation library and passing the differing props to the modal on navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same issue and after digging into this subject, I do not think there is any other way than taking the modal out of FlatList.
Seems that there is a bug in Android with a modal with textinput inside a FlatList, which caused when the keyboard expands.
When modal is outside of the FlatList, works like a charm.